# Extract variable length substring from string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to extract a text string and break it out into multiple columns, but I'm running into issues as there are variable lengths.

Example:

```
SHP123-SLD2345-DIV67-CRP89999-SUP-1234124
SHP1234-SLD234-DIV678-CRP0987-SUP-012
```

I would want to break out the string into 5 columns;
shp, sld, div, crp, sup

I also have a few odd rows with something like this;

```
 SHP12345-SLD23431-DIV4231-CRP432432-SUP-123-hello
```

the '123-hello' would still be considered a SUP.

The expected output would be something similar to this:

```
SHP123
SLD2345
DIV67
CRP89999
SUP-1234124

SHP1234
SLD234
DIV678
CRP0987
SUP-012
```

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: sql server 2016

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Is this input data or stored data? Why is it in this format?

Comment: this is stored data. I'm not sure why it was stored in this format, but I do not have access to change the transactional system as that would be the ideal case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you what you need:

```
declare @var nvarchar(max) = 'SHP12345-SLD2345987-DIV67-CRP89999-SUP-1234124'
--declare @var nvarchar(max) = '123-hello'

select
    @var
    , case when charindex('shp', @var, 0) <> 0
            then substring(@var, charindex('shp', @var, 0), charindex('-', @var, charindex('shp', @var, 0)) - charindex('shp', @var, 0)) 
        else NULL
        end [shp]
    , case 
        when charindex('sld', @var, 0) <> 0
            then substring(@var, charindex('sld', @var, 0), charindex('-', @var, charindex('sld', @var, 0)) - charindex('sld', @var, 0))
        else NULL
        end [sld]
    , case 
        when charindex('div', @var, 0) <> 0
            then substring(@var, charindex('div', @var, 0), charindex('-', @var, charindex('div', @var, 0)) - charindex('div', @var, 0))
        else NULL
        end [div]
    , case 
        when charindex('crp', @var, 0) <> 0
            then substring(@var, charindex('crp', @var, 0), charindex('-', @var, charindex('crp', @var, 0)) - charindex('crp', @var, 0))
        else NULL
        end [crp]
    , case 
        when charindex('sup', @var, 0) <> 0
            then substring(@var, charindex('sup', @var, 0), len(@var) + 1)
        else @var
    end [sup]
```

Comment: @js1229 You're welcome. Please don't forget to upvote / mark the answer as correct. Rewards keep me motivated to come back :)

Comment: This worked well, but how do I also include those with more than 4 char after shp, sld, etc. to the query?

Comment: @js1229 What do you mean? Can you update your question with more details?

Comment: Excellent! Thank you